# jQuery DatePicker inline highlight certain dates

Tags: jquery-ui

My problem is that the calendar is rendering before the JSON response is sent to the browser. In other words when we get to the array search my array is empty. How would I fix this?

UPDATED: I gave up on trying to request more dates on month change, so now I just get about 6 months worth of events on my first call and display it all at once. Below is the working code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var actionCalDates = [];
        //var orgID = 0;
        var currentDate = new Date();
        dateCount = 0;
        getDates(1, currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getFullYear());

        function displayCalendar() {
            $("#calendar").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                beforeShowDay: function (thedate) {
                    var theday = (thedate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + thedate.getDate() + "/" + thedate.getFullYear();
                    //console.log("Before the if my array contains: " + actionCalDates);
                    if ($.inArray(theday, actionCalDates) == -1) {
                        //console.log(theday + " Not Found");
                        return [false, "", ""];
                    } else {
                        //console.log(theday + " Found");
                        return [true, "specialDate", "Actions Today"];
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        function getDates(orgID, month, year) {
            dateCount += 1;
            if (dateCount < 4) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Calendar/getEvents",
                    data: {
                        'orgID': orgID,
                        'month': month,
                        'year': year
                    },
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        //console.log(result);
                        for (var i in result) {
                            actionCalDates.push(result[i]);
                            //console.log("Pushed to the array: " + actionCalDates[i]);
                        }
                        //console.log("Array currently holds: " + actionCalDates);
                        displayCalendar();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Code Behind C# controller:

```
public JsonResult getEvents(int orgID, int month, int year)
    {
        DateTime orgDate = Convert.ToDateTime(month + "/" + orgID + "/" + year);
        var fromDate = orgDate;
        var toDate = orgDate.AddMonths(7); //last month and the next 6 months

        var events = db.Events.Where(e => e.StartDate >= fromDate && e.EndDate <= toDate).ToArray();
        var eventlist = from e in events
                        select new
                        {
                            date = e.StartDate.ToString(),
                        };

        List<string> EventDates = new List<string>();

        foreach (var currentEvent in eventlist)
        {
            DateTime dt;
            dt = Convert.ToDateTime(currentEvent.date.ToString());
            EventDates.Add(dt.Month + "/" + dt.Day + "/" + dt.Year);
        }

        return Json(EventDates, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not putting the `$("#calendar").datepicker({` call inside the ajax `success:` handler:

```
success: function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    for (var i in result) {
        actionCalDates.push(result[i]);
        console.log("Pushed to the array: " + actionCalDates[i]);
    }
    //actionCalDates = actionCalDates.concat(result);
    console.log("Array currently holds: " + actionCalDates);
    //getDates(orgID, month + 1, year);
    //getDates(orgID, month - 1, year);

    //Now we have filled the array, let's create our calendar..
    $("#calendar").datepicker({
        ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it still doesn't work the way I wanted, which is to update the list of events when the month changes, but at least now I get 6 months worth of events and display them all at once.

Comment: You can set an event handler on the datepicker month change (there should be some event for this), then redo what you want to get things working after the change.

Comment: if you want to update list of events when month changes.. you can do so by handling that on "onChangeMonthYear()" method of datepicker. http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onChangeMonthYear

Answer (score 0):

Put the code that renders the calendar into some arbitrary function, then put a call to that function in your ajax({success: }) function

ie

```
function renderCalendar(){
  $("#calendar").datepicker({
        ...

  });
}

success: function (result) {
                      ...

                    renderCalendar();
                }
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing just this. I still couldn't get a new list when the month changes but oh well. It will do for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the method you want is called onChangeMonthYear.

I have used it in a [tutorial I wrote up](http://stevethomas.com.au/jquery/jquery-datepicker-ajax-request-to-highlight-days-from-mysql.html). It's probably not the prettiest code ever written however it does seem to be basically working.